# Linear Algebra Matrix Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series

I am having trouble showing that $e^AX = Xe^A$ for all $n$ by $n$ matrices $X$ where $A$ is an invertible $n$ by $n$ matrix iff $AX = XA$ for all $X$.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. Counterexample:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-2\pi\\ 2\pi&0\end{pmatrix},\ e^A=I.
$$
Then $A$ is invertible and $e^A$ commutes with every $2\times2$ matrix $X$, but $A$ only commutes with matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&-b\\ b&a\end{pmatrix}$.

What *is* true, though, is the following: if $A$ and $X$ are given matrices, then $e^{tA}X=Xe^{tA}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $AX=XA$. The "if" part is trivial and the "only if" part can be shown by evaluating the derivatives of both sides of the equation $e^{tA}X=Xe^{tA}$ at $t=0$.

Comment: Why is $e^A=I$?

Comment: @TongZhang The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm2\pi i$, so $A$ can be diagonalized as $A=P\operatorname{diag}(2\pi i,-2\pi i)P^{-1}$ and $e^A=P\operatorname{diag}(e^{2\pi i},e^{-2\pi i})P^{-1}=I$. If you only work over reals, you may also note that $A=2\pi J$ where $J=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Since $J^2=-I$, you can deduce that $e^A=I$ using the series expansion of $e^A$.

Answer (score 1):

An idea:

$$e^AX=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}A^nX\\Xe^A=X\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}A^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}XA^n$$

Comment: yeah that proves one direction, but I can't seem to prove the other direction.

Comment: Oh nevermind...I guess I was being silly

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}A^nX=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}XA^n$ implies that $AX = XA.$

Comment: A further idea, @Kathy: 

$$e^AX=Xe^A\;,\;\;\forall \,X\iff e^A=kI\;,\;\;0\neq k\in\Bbb F\Longrightarrow e^{tr.\, A}=\det e^A=k^n\implies tr. A=n\log k $$

Now check that if some element off the main diagonal in $\,A\,$ is non-zero then $\,e^AX\neq Xe^A\,$ for some matrix $\,X\,$